# Regex to catch all characters except numbers AND list of words

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm sure similar questions have been asked but there also seems to be a little twist to my needs so I can't get it working exactly as it should.

Using javascript I want to strip a string for all characters unless it matches some patterns. I.e. I want to keep all numbers and expressions like `%`, `million`, `billion` or `320b` even.

I intend to match all characters that should be stripped, i.e.

> I want to mark all non numb**3**ers but not **million**, **billion**, **20123** etc. The thing is I also don't want to mark **30billion** for instance or **30%**.

So far I'm stuck at `(?:(?![0-9]).)+` but that only gives me

> I want to mark all non numb**3**ers but not million, billion, **20123** etc. The thing is I also don't want to mark **30**billion for instance or **30**%.

#### EDIT

Actually I just realized that I am able to highlight the correct places with the following regex

```
(?:[0-9]|[0-9]?million|[0-9]?billion|[0-9]?%)
```

But how do I then join these matches into a single string? My endgoal is

```
3 million billion 20123 30billion 30%
```

using javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `match + join` operations:

```js
s = `I want to mark all non numb3ers but not million, billion, 20123 etc. The thing is I also don't want to mark 30billion for instance or 30%`;

var r = s.match(/\d*[mb](?:illion)?\b|\d+%?/ig).join(' ');

console.log(r);
//=> 3 million billion 20123 30billion 30%
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\d*`: Match 0 or more digits
- `[mb]`: Match `m` or `b`
- `(?:illion)?`: optionally match `illion`
- `\b`: Assert a word boundary
- `|`: OR
- `\d+%?`: Match 1+ digits optionally followed by `%`